# Talend Open Studio: delimited file with semi colon and header with quotes

Tags: etl, talend

I have a delimited file that is delimited by semi colon.
The first row in this file is the header, and the header tokens are in double quotes: an example is below:

"name", "telephone", "age", "address", "y"

When using the tFileDelimited and tMap and you pull the fields in, they look like this with underscores around the fields:
_name_, _telephone_, _age_, _address_, Column05

SO it seems that the fields, the double quote is changed to underscore character and for some reason the last field is a single character without the quotes, but  Talend seems to ignore this field name and gives its own default.

Just wondering if anyone has encountered this kind of behaviour and whether one should use a regex to remove the double quotes, to preprocess this first.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to remove extra blank spaces in the first row, between header tokens. If you use Metadata to import your file, you should have the right names appearing, (just check the options : 'heading rows as column names' and "\"" as the text enclosure)

Comment: Hi Corentin, that was helpful. But once i did that, I also noticed that other certain columns were then renamed to generic format of : Column04, for example. I think i know the reason. One of the column headers was called 'default' --> Column04. I guess in Talend the word 'default' is a reserved word. My question now is, how many reserved words do we have to watch out for.

Comment: I know some of them, but I don't know if there is a list somewhere : 'public', 'private', 'null', 'this','final', 'implements' are reserved for example. If you have a doubt, open the schema of a component, add a new column and type the name you want to test. Talend will automatically check if the name is OK.

Comment: Hi Corentin, thanks for your feedback i really appreciate this. I tried it out and was able to get things to work. I will choose your answer as the correct reply to my question. Thanks again!